# How to implement search with two terms for a collection?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

So, currently I have a collection of items where I want the user to be able to search using the name and some random text from the collection.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
    public IEnumerable<Item> items = new[]
    {
        new Item { ItemId = 1, ItemName = "Apple", ItemDescription = "crispy, sweet", ItemPairing = "Walnut"},
        new Item { ItemId = 2, ItemName = "Pear", ItemDescription = "slightly tart", ItemPairing = "Cheese"},
        new Item { ItemId = 3, ItemName = "Banana", ItemDescription = "good source of potassium", ItemPairing = "Honey" },
        new Item { ItemId = 4, ItemName = "Chocolate", ItemDescription = "Sweet and rich melting flavor", ItemPairing = "Wine"}
    };


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Search(string search)
    {
        return View("Index", items.Where(n => n.ItemName.StartsWith(search))); 
    }
```

Here's the search part on the view:

```
<p>
    <b>Search for Name:</b> 
    @Html.TextBox("ItemName", "", new { @class = "form-control" })  
    <b>Search for Text:</b>
    @Html.TextBox("ItemText", "", new { @class = "form-control" })

    <input id="search" type="submit" value="Search" onclick="search(ItemName,ItemText)" />
</p>

<script>
    function search(ItemName, ItemText) {
        $("search").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Items/Search",
                data: {ItemName, ItemText},
                datatype: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

So that it can look something like this:

[image: SearchPage]

I want it so that when the user types in Apple for Name and Crispy for text, they can find the Apple item from my collection. I also want it so that if they type in either Name or Text, it will still return a matched item.

I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What if your `onclick()` function? Your `Search()` method will also need 2 parameters, one for `ItemName` and one for `ItemText` (matching the names of your 2 textboxes)

Comment: Ah right, I was wondering is it better to pass it as one string or two strings?

Comment: If you only passed one string, how would you know which property to search in :)

Comment: Good point, I'm now passing in two parameters, how should I handle search?

Comment: What is you current `onclick` function? Are you making an ajax call? (your controller method seems to suggest otherwise)

Comment: Yes I am making an AJAX call. Opps, I should have made a JsonResult

Comment: Either that or a partial view

Comment: I added my post above to show you my ajax call.

Comment: I honestly suggest using partial views (look them up). But I hope the answer bellow can be a guidance on how that could be done. Implementation of partials isn't hard. Change `JsonResult` with `ActionResult` and instead of `Json` return `Partial("some/page", newItems);`, and, of course, just create a partial with accepts `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `onclick` attribute from the submit button and change it to

```
<button type="button" id="search">Search</button>
```

and change the script to

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Search", "Items")';
$("#search").click(function () {
  $.post(url, { ItemName: $('#ItemName').val(), ItemText: $('#ItemText').val() }, function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
  });
})
```

Note you may want to consider making it `$.get()` rather than `$.post()`

and change the controller method to accept the inputs from both textboxes

```
public PartialViewResult Search(string itemName, string itemText)
{
  var items = ??
  // filter the data (adjust to suit your needs)
  if (itemName != null)
  {
    items = items.Where(x => x.ItemName.ToUpperInveriant().Contains(itemName.ToUpperInveriant()) 
  }
  if (itemText != null)
  {
    items = items.Where(x => x.ItemDescription.ToUpperInveriant().Contains(itemText.ToUpperInveriant()) 
  }
  // query you data
    return PartialView("_Search", items); 
}
```

Side note: Its not clear what the logic for search is - i.e. if you enter search text in both textboxes, do you want an `and` or an `or` search

Assuming the view in the view in the question is `Index.cshtml`, then it will include the following html

```
<div id="result">
  @Html.Action("Search") // assumes you want to initially display all items
</div>
```

and the `_Search.cshtml` partial would be something like

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  // html to display the item properties
}
```

Comment: Opps, minor typo. Thanks!

Comment: Also you will want to change the view you return from `Index.cshtml` to something else assuming `Index.cshtml` is the main view that these textboxes are in.

Comment: Good point! I just realized that too as well. I have it return the correct match search but because I was returning the same view, nothing happened. So I have to return a new view with common elements from the boxes above?

Comment: See update (not sure if you want to initially display all items or not)

Comment: Thank you so much! For the most part, this is what I want (I don't want to display the data initially). Now you're absolutely right... I have to decide if I want a search for both boxes, should I do an AND or OR. Currently, it's an OR. Hmm..

Comment: One other suggestion - in the partial view add something like`@if(!Model.Any()){ <div>The search did not return any results</div> }`

Answer (score 1):

While CStrouble's answer will work, if you're into AJAX calls and want to sort this in a single page, you might consider using AJAX and JQuery calls.

With AJAX & JQuery:

```
var search = function(itemName, itemText) {
    //note that if you want RESTful link, you'll have to edit the Routing config file.
    $ajax.get('/controller/action/itemName/itemText/', function(res) {
        //do stuff with results... for instance:
        res.forEach(function(element) {
            $('#someElement').append(element);
        });
    });
};
```

And the action:

```
public JsonResult SearchAction(itemName, itemText) {
    List<Item> newItems = items.Where(x => x.ItemName.ToUpperInveriant().Contains(itemName.ToUpperInveriant()) 
                                        || x.ItemDescription.ToUpperInveriant().Contains(itemText.ToUpperInveriant())
                                        || x.ItemPairing.ToUpperInveriant().Contains(itemText.ToUpperInveriant()));
    return Json.Encode(newItems.ToArray());
}
```

Note that I'm not home, so there might be some syntax errors.

Alright, so say I want to return a partial, instead of a simple array:

first, change the action to:

```
public ActionResult SearchAction(itemName, itemText) {
    List<Item> newItems = items.Where(x => x.ItemName.ToUpperInveriant().Contains(itemName.ToUpperInveriant()) 
                                        || x.ItemDescription.ToUpperInveriant().Contains(itemText.ToUpperInveriant())
                                        || x.ItemPairing.ToUpperInveriant().Contains(itemText.ToUpperInveriant()));
    return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/MyPartialView.cshtml", newItems);
}
```

And you create a partial view in the directory you specified, taking the model that you transferred (`newItems`)

```
@model IEnumerable<Path.to.Item>

<h3>Results</h3>
<ul>
@foreach(var item in model)
{
    <li>@item.Name - @item.Description</li>
}
</ul>
```

and now when you receive the jquery response:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Items/Search",
            data: {ItemName, ItemText},
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
   //since data is the HTML partial itself.
   //if you have firebug for Mozilla firefox, you can see what I'm
   //talking about
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I gotten some of the syntax errors out of the way. One left: Controller.Json(object)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context. That error is shown on the line for Json.Encode. did I need to import something for Json? I forgot.

Comment: I believe you have to implement a library to parse Json. Did you try using CTRL + . (dot) while selecting the method?

Comment: Just using Json worked for me, I have a question. if I use partial views, can I still use AJAX to call the controller for partial view?

Comment: Yeap, since the partial simply gets rendered just like any other HTML, you can always overload a partial view. Just as long as you have something to overload over. So, for instance, I always start my partials with a div that has an ID that I know I can override when I want to load another partial, or reload the same one. I'll try to create a small example in the answer, so you know what I mean.

Comment: edited. It's not pretty lookin' - since I'm blind-coding it, but it might help you with what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider converting both strings to upper or lower, depending on your search requirements.  The below code assumes the search is case-insensitive.

```
public ActionResult Search(string search)
{
    string upperSearch = search.ToUpperInvariant();
    return View("Index", items.Where(n => 
        n.ItemName.ToUpperInvariant().StartsWith(search) || 
        n.ItemDescription.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(search))); 
}
```

with the Or condition it will match if either the text or the name matches.  If they match different items (like Apple and Tart), you may need to consider what happens in that use-case, but in this case it will return both Apple and Pear.

Comment: hmm okay but if I also have a category called ItemPairing so that the second search box should search for ItemPairing or ItemDescription. In that case, can't I do something like ItemName.StartsWith(search) && ItemDescription.Contains(search) || ItemPairing.Contains(search)? Something like that?